# How can I get the result of installation when prompting to user on Android 11?

Tags: java, android

I'm building a background service app without any **UI** on Android 11. Right now I'm using below code to ask for user consent to install apk with permission "SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

With this code, the program will be able to prompt to user for consent of installation when there is a new apk coming in.
But could someone tell me how can I get the result of user's choice and the result of whether installation success or fails? I know we can use **startActivityForResult** but since this is a background service app, I'm not able to use that since it doesn't have any activity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is too late for you. What I use to get a callback is packageInstaller.registerSessionCallback(new PackageInstaller.SessionCallback() {}. You can implement a bunch of overriden methods inside this which will help you monitor the progress. Again I use this inside activity and haven't tried it in a service. Also, even though I got a call back for user cancelling the pop up, I couldn't get one for installing update successfully. These are my observations. Hope this would give you some insights.